# PHP Radio button selection is pulling through blank?

Tags: php, html

I am just trying to figure out why even though i have a value selected, my isset is pulling through that there is no data selected.

The HTML:

```
<form action="submitBackgroundImage.php" id="submitBackground">
      <input type="radio" name="background" value="lake" checked="checked"> Lake.jpg<br>
      <input type="radio" name="background" value="dock"> Dock.jpg<br>
      <input type="radio" name="background" value="forest"> Forest.jpg<br>
      <button type="submit" form="submitBackground" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The PHP in "submitBackgroundImage.php":

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['background'])) {
    echo "Data Selected";
}
else
{
    echo "No Data Selected";
};

?>
```

This returns:

[image]

I'm a PHP novice so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: add method = post

Comment: how did i miss that, thank you.

Comment: *"any advice is appreciated."* - Enabling error reporting is a good tool.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Is that built into PHP? or do you mean in the browser?

Comment: Error reporting is built-in to the server's configuration file. If the server you're on doesn't let you modify that, then you can use the "catch and display" method as shown in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: There is one thing though that everyone below missed and the fact of the matter is that, `<form>` defaults to a GET method if POST isn't specifically implied. *That* would have made for better answers, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the method.

```
<form action="submitBackgroundImage.php" id="submitBackground" method="POST">
```

Comment: how did i miss that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Define the method in form element so that you will get the data when you submit the form

```
<form action="submitBackgroundImage.php" method="POST" id="submitBackground">
      <input type="radio" name="background" value="lake" checked="checked"> Lake.jpg<br>
      <input type="radio" name="background" value="dock"> Dock.jpg<br>
      <input type="radio" name="background" value="forest"> Forest.jpg<br>
      <button type="submit" form="submitBackground" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```